# Underscore not respected in on instance of terminal

Tags: sed, echo, stdout, tr, ubuntu-20.04

I have a strange problem when trying to define a variable or even echo it when its content has an underscore.

My original problem was to replace spaces and put the underscore in a string. So far so good. I used sed to make the replacement and assign it to a variable .. I'm stuck on that for hours.

It happens that when presenting the underscore the console is not effective, making me think the following: My variable is not with the underscore and the console is correct on the output; Or my variable has the underscore and the console is limited to not displaying it.

eg:

```
"the string" ... some process ... "the string"
```

> when i was expecting

```
"the string" ... some process ... "the_string"
```

**Follows the "best" failed attempts.**

Using tr and put the stdout directly in to a var

```
FOO=$(tr -s ' ' '_' <<< "the string"); echo $FOO;
```

Creating a file and reading it to a var
(proof that the variable has the correct value, because the file has the underscore)

```
echo "the string" | sed "s/ /_/" 1>echo; FOO=$(cat echo); echo $FOO;
```

**The "original" command stdout works well**

```
tr -s ' ' '_' <<< "the string"
```

```
echo "the string" | sed "s/ /_/"
```

If I change the underscore for the dash, everything goes well. So, what's going on that?

## EDIT:

The same command in a new terminal worked just enter image description herefine. The root cause is a mistery

[Old console stdout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXrcR.png)

[New console stdout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8X0V.png)

Comment: Are you saying that the output of `FOO=$(tr -s ' ' '_' <<< "the string"); echo $FOO;` is `the string`? If so, I can't reproduce this.

Comment: That's right. I don't understand why, but that's it.

Comment: And what happens when you write to the file first? There's a sentence in the description that I don't understand (Spanish?).

Comment: 1) `echo "the string" | sed "s/ /_/" 1>echo` ??? Highly ill-advised to create and use filenames that match command names. A maintenance nightmare when you get promoted and someone else is having to maintain your code ;-) !  2) If MS-Windows is involved anywhere in the processing of your datafile, try `dos2unix myDataFile` and retest. Good luck.

Comment: @BenjaminW. i edited it.
So..
I went to get an evidence and for that I changed ~ / .bashrc in order to hide the name of the machine. Then, I opened a new terminal and executed the command ... the underscore appeared. Why?

Comment: @shellter it's just a didactic example, not for production. Thanks for the advice, anyway.

Comment: The new output has a stray underscore after a few blanks, what's up with that?

Comment: @BenjaminW. That was the top of a square that was cut in the print

Comment: I found a solution to "restore" my old console instance. I just posted the solution for history, but it doesn't make much sense in how the stdout was messed up.

Comment: Well, if your `IFS` was set to include `_`, that  explains why `my_string` is printed as `my string` when unquoted – word splitting replaces the `_`.

Answer (score 2):

The terminal are trying to undestand de variable $FOO like a field of array type, so IFS is applied and the string is splited, generating the output without the underscore.
Quoting you variable will make then to be understand has a field of string type.

So you can restore your $IFS fiel to his default, or you can quoting you variable.

**Reassigning $ IFS to its default value will resolve the result.**

```
 $ IFS=''
```

**Quoting your variable in the script.**

```
FOO=$(tr -s ' ' '_' <<< "the string"); echo "$FOO";
```

Comment: The assignments can't have blanks around `=`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. My bad. Edited

Comment: Notice that the problem wouldn't have occurred with proper quoting, `echo "$FOO"`